# How to get one or more Http sampler Response in Beanshell PostProcessor

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have a Controller which has 5 http samplers. I would like to get the 5 http sampler response details in beanshell postprocessor. Is it possible to get more than one http sampler responses in beanshell postprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to execute a certain script for all those 5 samplers, then placing the `Beanshell Postprocessor' in the same level as shown in the below picture will do. The same post processor will get executed for all the 5 samplers.

[image]

Ie, Once 'A' is executed, the post processor is executed and You can access the A's response. Once the B is executed, You can access only B's response. Not A's.
This is as per the design!